# XSL-FO | FO: Tags are being removed

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I'm currently using XSL for a work project and I'm facing an issue.

I'm trying to read values for a database that look like this:

```
<fo:block font-weight='bold>hello</fo:block>
```

and it seems that XSL is stripping the `<fo:block>` element because it gives me text only ( I only see Hello, not in bold, and it doesn't behave like a block element ). I feel like, somehow, that XSL interprets the value read from the DB as a string, and strip of the `<fo>` tags, leaving my with text only.

Any idea what could be done in order that my styling get preserved?

( Obviously this example have been simplified, the text to be displayed is longer than that )

EDIT : Self answered for future references

Comment: What technology do you use to compile the `.fo` file? Do you have access to that file, before the processor creates the output?

Comment: Also, do you bind the prefix `fo` to XSL-FO? Double-check that, your problem sounds exactly like the FO processor ignoring it because of wrong namespaces.

Comment: @Boldewyn yes it is prefixed, the rest of my template is written using `fo`, only the part read from the DB seem to be a problem

Comment: @Boldewyn and yes i have access to that .fo file, we will check to see if everything thing is ok. Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you show the XSLT? Sounds like you're using an `xsl:value-of` instead of an `xsl:copy-of` or an `xsl:apply-templates` with no matching template to copy the element.

Comment: @DanielHaley that was my first thought, too, but then you should see the `<fo>` tag as plain text in the output.

Comment: this is the xslt
```<fo:block-container>

  <fo:block>
    <xsl:value-of select='/fulfill-list/ticket-list/list-item/eventTicketContent/xmlTicketContent/ticketdescription'/>
  </fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
```

after having inspected the `.fo` i can confirm that the `fo` tags have been stripped off. ( sorry for the bad identation )

Comment: To be clear, does the fragment you have in the database declare and use the FO namespace with e.g. `<fo:block font-weight='bold' xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">hello</fo:block>`? How do you pull it from the database and insert it?

Comment: @MartinHonnen it's declared at the beggining of the template ( `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.0">` ) but not from the value fetched from the db ( well actually it is, but i read the data from this element, it's on `ticketdescription` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As first i wanted to thanks you all to have taken the time to answer me. I'm very very very glad to see SO community is such strong.

I have solved my problem this way :

```
 <xsl:for-each select="/fulfill-list/ticket-list/list-item/eventTicketContent/xmlTicketContent/ticketdescription/node()">
      <xsl:copy-of select="child::node()" />
    </xsl:for-each>
```

I don't really know what happened beneath the hood and why the `<fo>` tags were removed, but they were. Looping through all of them and using `<xsl:copy-of>` did the trick.

Once again, a big thanks to y'all !

Comment: There is no need for that `for-each` with a nested `copy-of`, you can as well use a single `<xsl:copy-of select="/fulfill-list/ticket-list/list-item/eventTicketContent/xmlTicketContent/ticketdescription/*/node()" />` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments you want to change `<xsl:value-of select='/fulfill-list/ticket-list/list-item/eventTicketConte‌​nt/xmlTicketContent/‌​ticketdescription'/>` to `<xsl:copy-of select='/fulfill-list/ticket-list/list-item/eventTicketConte‌​nt/xmlTicketContent/‌​ticketdescription'/>` (or perhaps `<xsl:copy-of select='/fulfill-list/ticket-list/list-item/eventTicketConte‌​nt/xmlTicketContent/‌​ticketdescription/node()'/>`).